# append a link with json data as a

Tags: jquery, append

I send some json data via data- attrbute from html tag to jquery .. and it works perfect , for example

HTML :

```
<li class="get-info" data-path="some path" data-info='{"jid": 1, "name": "Json","post": { "extra":"data"}  }' >
    <a href="#"> link </a>
</li>
```

I can get my data-info json opject in jquery easily , for example:

```
var sourceInfo = $('.get-info').data('info');  
alert(sourceInfo.name) // wil alert the name : Json  ... which is perfect,
```

BUT, the problem is when I append the same link via jquery like this :

// i get all links from json file .. and then append them all in a ul

// this is just a simple code "copy paste"  from my project ..

```
var items = [];  
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(res), function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li class="get-info" data-path="some path" data-info='+{"jid": 1, "name": "' + val.name + '","post": { "extra":"data"}  } +' ><a href="#"> ' + val.name + '  </a></li>');

    // or 
    var getInfo = {"jid": 1, "name": "Json","post": { "extra":"data"}  }; 
    items.push('<li class="get-info" data-path="some path"  data-info="' + getInfo + '"><a href="#"> ' + val.name + '   </a></li>');    
});                    
// append all my links to a ul 
$('#someDiv').append('<ul>'+  items.join('') +'</ul> ');
```

now, when I click on the appended .get-info link ,  I can NOT get the data-info= json object ..
Actually when I alert($('.get-info').data('info')) , I get [object object] , but I can not get the values from the keys within the object

ex:

```
jQuery('.get-info').live('click', function (e) {    
var sourceInfo = $('.get-info').data('info');  
alert(sourceInfo) // = I get :  [object object]! 
alert(sourceInfo.name) // = I get :  undefined!  

I still can get my data-path, 
var path = $('.get-info').data('path');  
alert(path)  // I get : some path
```

});

**UPDATE**
You can check the example here : http://jsfiddle.net/Q6kKU/197/

I think my problem exactly something with " or ' with data-info=" {..} " , but I really tried my best for hours but no luck ..

Any help ?
Thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to stringify your object first before you append it to a string. Use `JSON.stringify(getInfo)` instead of `getInfo` in the `items.push` line.

Comment: I had up-voted you, but now I take it back since you added that line about putting quotes around an object literal.  JSON is more strict than JavaScript object literals.  He may change that object some day, and wonder why everything broke.

Comment: Good point, didn't think about that. I'll take that out. Thanks

Comment: Guys, it didn't work! when I JSON.stringify(getInfo) and then print the sourceInfo = $('.get-info').data('info'); .. I get just " { " !
and still get undefined when I alert(sourceInfo.name) .. am I doing something wrong? I'll try to post a simple in jsfiddle.com in seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to turn your object into a JSON text. Right now you're just getting the default `toString` output (`"[object Object]"`), which comes from [`Object.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

```
items.push('<li class="get-info" data-path="some path"  data-info="' + JSON.stringify(getInfo) + '"><a href="#"> ' + val.name + '   </a></li>');
```